# Turkish characters are not displayed properly in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, .net-7.0

In my MVC project that I developed on the .net 7 platform, Turkish characters are displayed incorrectly in my JavaScript codes in HTML.  I checked and tried all similar topics opened here, but even though I tried all the scenarios in my own project, I could not find a way to solve my problem. I am waiting for your help in this matter. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="tr">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
    <script>
           console.log("işlem");
    </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

[export console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcBQ8.png)

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4xOw.png)

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXNmz.png)

[myscript example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/123AX.png)

[example message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG2se.png)

I added screenshots, I cannot solve such errors in many places. The messages appearing here do not come from the database. I also checked the server or database language character settings. The data coming from the database arrives properly. The problem is that any Turkish data I write on the HTML also becomes an error.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Thank you for your warning. However, I uploaded the images I uploaded to serve as a representative example. Actually, my problem is that I am looking for a solution for the code I wrote above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest. I'm glad there are helpful people like you. After saving and editing the source files as utf-8 again, my problem was solved :) @Yogi

Comment: Does the font you are using have those characters in it? Maybe try switching to a full Unicode font and see if it makes any difference.